# styling with padding when using before pseudo

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

html

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="active">Tab-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2">Tab-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3">Tab-3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-contents" id="tab-1" style="display: block;">
    some text
</div>
```

css

```css
.tab-contents{
    background: #2b2a26;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    clear: both;
}


#tabs {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 4px 0;
    float: right;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 -4px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#tabs li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border-radius: 19px 19px 0 0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 47px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 145px;
}

#tab-1:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f00;
    padding-top: 10px; /* not working as expected but giving padding to bottom */
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SmN28/1/)

Within gray box the red box should behave the padding top. How can I do that?

Comment: its getting padding top whats wrong?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/SmN28/5/

Comment: the red box is not getting padding top. it should go under the gray box.

Comment: Do you mean `margin-top`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use padding-top to `.tab-contents` instead.

```
.tab-contents{
    background: #2b2a26;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SmN28/2/)

Alternatively, You could use `position: relative; top: 10px;`  to your `#tab-1:before` instead of padding-top.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SmN28/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to use `margin-top` instead of `padding-top`?

http://jsfiddle.net/SmN28/4/